# How can i export html table which is created dynamically to pdf format in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have created html table dynamically in asp.net. Now i want to export that displaying table into pdf format. I have used following code to export to pdf format.

```
protected void BtnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SearchBooking.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    //tblPayslip.AllowPaging = false;
    tblPayslip.DataBind();
    tblPayslip.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.End(); 
   }
```

and its giving me error as 
The document has no pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing your document before writing it in response?

Change

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

To

```
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

Comment: I have tried this code also, but getting same error